# Ubuntu as a bandwidth throttling box on windows network

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, routing, bandwidth

I need to test the performance of some applications over different capacity connections (broadband, EFM, LAN extension etc). How would i configure an Ubuntu server to sit between the main network (17.16.x.x) and throttle the flow to and from a machine the other side of the throttle server?

I've looked at ProxyARP, but that (as far as i can tell) only handles the routing, not the bandwidth. I need something that throttles all network traffic not just HTTP(S) etc.

I have a Dell R610 (dual quad core Xeon, 98Gb RAM) with multiple nics and ubuntu server installed.

In case i wasn't clear the below is what i am hoping to achieve:

**Internet** <====> **Core Switch Stack** <====>**nic1** - **R610** - **nic2** <====> **Switch** <====> **TestingServer**

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: Check out this question on superuser.com http://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface

Comment: Thanks Adam, that only seems to apply to the throttling on one machine though, rather than the linux box working as both a arp proxy and throttler. Unless of course i missed something while reading?